# Storing Results from SSH Shell in Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, shell, ssh

**currently developing a Flutter application that communicates with various network devices, including an OLT (Optical Line Terminal) VSOL device. Unlike other devices where I can directly fetch results using `sshClient.run` , for the OLT VSOL device, I need to spawn a shell in the SSH session first and then capture the results from the shell stream.**

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
// SSH connection setup for OLT VSOL device
sessions[i] = SSHClient(
  await SSHSocket.connect('10.10.93.10', 22),
  username: 'admin',
  onPasswordRequest: () => 'admin',
);
shell = await sessions[i].shell();
stdout.addStream(shell.stdout); // Stream to print results to console
stderr.addStream(shell.stderr);
stdin.cast<Uint8List>().listen(shell.write);


Uint8List commandBytes = utf8.encode('enable\n');
shell.write(commandBytes);
```

My challenge is to capture and store the results obtained from the shell in a variable within the Flutter application, so that I can organize and process them accordingly before setting them to the device result.

I've considered using `StreamBuilder`to capture the stream output, but I'm not sure how to efficiently store this data in a variable for further manipulation.

Could someone provide guidance on the best approach to achieve this? Any code examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**What I tried:**
I attempted to capture the output from the SSH shell by setting up a stream to print the results to the console. I used the `stdout.addStream(shell.stdout)` line to capture the output stream from the shell.

**What I expected to happen:**
I expected that by adding the shell's standard output stream to the `stdout stream,` I would be able to capture the output of the commands executed in the shell and store them in a variable within the Flutter application.

**What actually resulted:**
While I was able to see the output of the commands printed to the console, I struggled to efficiently capture and store this output in a variable within the Flutter application for further processing and organization. I'm unsure of the best approach to achieve this and would appreciate guidance on how to effectively capture and store the output from the SSH shell in a Flutter variable.